# How to compute the monstrous $ \int_0^{\frac{e-1}{e}}{\frac{x(2-x)}{(1-x)}\frac{\log\left(\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2-2x}\right)\right)}{2-2x+x^2}dx} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

A friend told me, that he found a closed form for the following integral:
$$
\int_0^{\frac{e-1}{e}}{\frac{x(2-x)}{(1-x)}\frac{\log\left(\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2-2x}\right)\right)}{\left(2-2x+x^2\right)}dx}
$$
I don't know if he's just messing around with me, but I wonder if this integral admits a closed form. I tried to expand the $\log(\log)$ term into a power series, but things got worse. So any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can do it. Let $u=\ln\left(1 + \frac{x^2}{2-2x}\right)$ and then do integration by parts.

Comment: Observing $\log\left(\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2-2x}\right)\right) = \log(\log(2-2x+x^2) - \log(2-2x))$ could be useful

Comment: @Blex: how could it be useful, can you explain?i don't understand please

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Notice, we have $$\int_{0}^{\frac{e-1}{e}}\frac{x(2-x)}{1-x}\frac{\log\left(\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2-2x}\right)\right)}{2-2x+x^2}dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{e-1}{e}}\frac{x(2-x)}{1-x}\frac{\log\left(\log\left(\frac{2-2x+x^2}{2-2x}\right)\right)}{2-2x+x^2}dx$$

Let, $$\log\left(\frac{2-2x+x^2}{2-2x}\right)=u$$ 
$$\implies \frac{d}{dx}\left(\log\left(\frac{2-2x+x^2}{2-2x}\right)\right)=\frac{d}{dx}(u)$$ $$\frac{1}{\left(\frac{2-2x+x^2}{2-2x}\right)}\cdot \left(\frac{(2-2x)(-2+2x)-(2-2x+x^2)(-2)}{(2-2x)^2} \right)=\frac{du}{dx}$$
$$\left(\frac{2-2x}{2-2x+x^2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{2x(2-x)}{(2-2x)^2} \right)=\frac{du}{dx}$$ $$\frac{x(2-x)}{(1-x)}\frac{1}{(2-2x+x^2)}dx=du$$ Now, we have $$\int_{0}^{\log\left(\frac{e^2+1}{2e}\right)}\log(u)du$$

$$=\left[u\log(u)-u\right]_{0}^{\log\left(\frac{e^2+1}{2e}\right)}$$
$$=\left[u\log\left(\frac{u}{e}\right)\right]_{0}^{\log\left(\frac{e^2+1}{2e}\right)}$$

$$=\log\left(\frac{e^2+1}{2e}\right)\cdot\log\left(\frac{1}{e}\log\left(\frac{e^2+1}{2e}\right)\right)-\lim_{u\to 0}u\log\left(\frac{u}{e}\right)$$

$$=\log\left(\frac{e^2+1}{2e}\right)\cdot\log\left(\frac{1}{e}\log\left(\frac{e^2+1}{2e}\right)\right)-0$$

Hence, we get

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\int_{0}^{\frac{e-1}{e}}\frac{x(2-x)}{1-x}\frac{\log\left(\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2-2x}\right)\right)}{2-2x+x^2}dx}=\color{blue}{\log\left(\frac{e^2+1}{2e}\right)\cdot \log\left(\frac{1}{e}\log\left(\frac{e^2+1}{2e}\right)\right)}}$$

Comment: Finally, someone ended their answer with flavour!

Answer (score 4):

Here comes the help!
$$\mathcal{I}=(\varphi-1)\left(\ln(\varphi-1)-1\right)$$
$$\text{with}\qquad \varphi=\ln\left(\frac{1+e^{2}}{2}\right)$$
Namagiri is on fire today.

Comment: Beside Namagiri, both *Mathematica* and *Maple* could evaluate the integral in this form.

Comment: @user153012 and a friend of user109899 apparently.

Comment: What/ who is Namagiri?

Comment: How did you obtain this?  I would recommend posting a development of the solution rather than the end result, which apparently is available via Maple.

Comment: @Dr.MV  Compare the score of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1401363/73025) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/713518/73025) answer and then recommend me something again.

Comment: Thank you, but how to prove it by hand?

Comment: @user109899 Compute and simplify the derivative of $\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2-2x}\right)$.

Comment: @L.G.  So, you believe that receiving a high score is the goal here?  What do thise points do for you if I may ask?

Comment: @Dr.MV I am not asking myself such questions, although it might be that game aspects excite me more than helping people and stuff like that. This is especially true for "could-we-find-a-closed-form" questions where the askers only pretend that they don't know the answer. You might have noticed that the number of people who pressed the button "This answer is useful" in my example relate as 45:1 in the two cases. The incentive is thus very clear.

Comment: @L.G.  Two examples make up a very small sample on which to base a general conclusion ... especially when that person is so highly mathematically inclined as you are.

Comment: @Sky: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namagiri_Thayar

Comment: @L.G.: Could you also work your magic on [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311929) ? :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian I was not successful with that problem in spite of considerable effort.